# Google Cloud Vision API text detection google.gax.errors.RetryError: GaxError

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm new in Google API.
Recently, I use the Google Vision API but I met the following problem:

```
google.gax.errors.RetryError: GaxError(Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient, caused by <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, Insufficient tokens for quota 'DefaultGroup' and limit 'USER-100s' of service 'vision.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXX'.)>)
```

And I tried the solution about "Create the service accout" to generate the service json key and invoke it in py.script,
it will work first in almost 3~4 url, but it will error in next url.
This is my detect code:

```
import argparse
import io
from google.cloud import vision
vision_client = vision.Client.from_service_account_json('/Users/bruce0621/Downloads/esun-bank-adc1897dba67.json')
...
def detect_text_uri(uri):
    """Detects text in the file located in Google Cloud Storage or on the Web.
    """
    vision_client = vision.Client()
    image = vision_client.image(source_uri=uri)

    texts = image.detect_text()
    print('Texts:')

    for text in texts:
        print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))

        vertices = (['({},{})'.format(bound.x_coordinate, bound.y_coordinate)
                    for bound in text.bounds.vertices])

        print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
```

And I invoke the "detect.py" in another py.script:

```
detect.detect_text_uri('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Call:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/your/credentials.json
```

or

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

This will configure your environment to use the service account credential you downloaded.